# python dataframe group by with formulas and variable numbers of column

Tags: python, formula, pandas-groupby

I need to create a grouping data frame with a variable number of columns which has calculated fields.

Not sure even how to describe this so I made a small table attached.
There are always four sets of columns, the fifth column contains a formula making calculations on the other four preceding columns.

The problem is that I need to group the results and the formula should be calculated on sums of individual columns.

The question is how to make it assuming that I will have multiple groups of columns and multiple grouping criteria.

[image: table]

Comment: I see you're relatively inexperienced with SO, welcome! Typically for questions like these (i.e. tagged with `pandas`), the community expects to see your data in DataFrame format. Regarding your question specifically -- in your grouping example, you have a group where Age==3 and Gender==1, but it omits the 6th row of the original data. Is that a clerical error? It's also unclear if you mean to create the 5th columns first then aggregate or vice versa. Those results are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided your data in DataFrame format, I have made some assumptions about its structure. First, create some representative data.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

setdata = [[12, 4, 0, 0, 12, 3, 1, 0],
           [12, 5, 0, 0, 12, 2, 1, 0],
           [12, 4, 0, 0, 12, 3, 1, 0],
           [ 6, 0, 0, 0,  6, 0, 0, 0],
           [ 7, 4, 0, 1,  7, 1, 0, 0],
           [ 7, 5, 0, 1,  7, 2, 1, 0],
           [ 7, 4, 0, 2,  7, 2, 0, 0]]

df_sets = pd.DataFrame(setdata)
level0 = ['Set{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, df_sets.shape[-1] // 4 + 1)]
level1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df_sets.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(product(level0, level1))
df_sets.insert(0, 'Age', [3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6])
df_sets.insert(1, 'Gender', [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])
print(df_sets)
```

Output:

```
  Age Gender Set1          Set2         
                A  B  C  D    A  B  C  D
0   3      1   12  4  0  0   12  3  1  0
1   3      1   12  5  0  0   12  2  1  0
2   3      1   12  4  0  0   12  3  1  0
3   4      2    6  0  0  0    6  0  0  0
4   3      2    7  4  0  1    7  1  0  0
5   3      1    7  5  0  1    7  2  1  0
6   6      1    7  4  0  2    7  2  0  0
```

Then, you want to aggregate by age and gender.

```
df_grp = df_sets.groupby(['Age', 'Gender']).sum()
print(df_grp)
```

Output:

```
           Set1           Set2          
              A   B  C  D    A   B  C  D
Age Gender                              
3   1        43  18  0  1   43  10  4  0
    2         7   4  0  1    7   1  0  0
4   2         6   0  0  0    6   0  0  0
6   1         7   4  0  2    7   2  0  0
```

Then, compute and append the 5th column (here, "E") for each set and reorder the columns so each "E" column is printed along with its corresponding set.

```
for idx, grp in df_grp.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    df_grp[(idx, 'E')] = grp[idx][['B', 'C', 'D']].sum(axis=1) / grp[(idx, 'A')]
df_grp.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df_grp)
```

Output:

```
              A   B  C  D         E    A   B  C  D         E
Age Gender                                                  
3   1        43  18  0  1  0.441860   43  10  4  0  0.325581
    2         7   4  0  1  0.714286    7   1  0  0  0.142857
4   2         6   0  0  0  0.000000    6   0  0  0  0.000000
6   1         7   4  0  2  0.857143    7   2  0  0  0.285714
```